# Implementing Screen Streaming to RTMP in Flutter using Kotlin Native

Tags: flutter, kotlin

I am working on a streaming app where I need to stream the screen to RTMP. Despite extensive research and efforts, I haven't succeeded due to my limited experience.

I attempted to integrate the ThibaultBee's StreamPack library into a Kotlin Native app for screen streaming to RTMP, with the intention of using this app within my Flutter project. I expected to successfully capture the screen in the Kotlin app and stream it to an RTMP server. However, I encountered an issue where registerForActivityResult, necessary for screen capture permission, is not directly compatible with FlutterActivity, which is required for Flutter integration. My efforts to find alternative Android libraries for screen recording were also unsuccessful, as they all required registerForActivityResult. As a result, I couldn't achieve screen streaming functionality in my Flutter app as I had hoped.Is it possible to achieve screen streaming in a Flutter app, or is this an insurmountable challenge? Any guidance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.